# Windows 10 Feedback Hub for sideloaded UWP apps

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Feedback Hub can be launched from [sideloaded app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps) and the application is appearing in it's category list.

```
var launcher = Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement.StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.GetDefault();
await launcher.LaunchAsync();
```

For Microsoft Store applications there seams to be [Feedback Report page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/feedback-report) where developer can be notified about it's user feedbacks. What about apps which are not uploaded to Store, is there a way for developer to access user feedbacks? Are there maybe any additional options to configure Feedback Hub for such a use cases?

Answer (score 0):

Since your app is not listed in the app store, it cannot be included in the store ’s feedback system.

As a side loading application, you need to implement your own feedback channels. Here are some suggestions:

1. Provide contact email
2. Establish a server and database to store customer feedback
3. Use some group tools to create a communication group.